# Salesforce - Link developer account

Tags: salesforce

I have used a Docusign trail account which was linked to my salesforce earlier. The trail docusign account has expired.

I have created a new docusign developer account and would like to link to the salesforce org.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible - just uninstall the previous one and you should be able to do it. if not link it to a different salesforce Org.